# JAVA - Merge Join of two large sorted files into one sorted

Tags: java, sorting, merge

Is there a jar file or source code in java that implements merge join of two large files into one sorted? Or what is the best way to merge two large files in java ?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data is present in those files ? Sorting criteria for the data ?

Comment: This really sounds lazy

Comment: The two files contain sorted strings

Comment: I guess you could read (per line) both files and write those in a new file and always check which line of which file you need to write by comparing them. If needed I can provide some sample code.

Comment: Sure i can do that but then there is the I/O problem that will slow down the process for large files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use external merge sort for this purpose.
To understand external mergesort, refer this [link](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Weiss/L17-ExternalSortEX1.htm).

Here is code [link](https://github.com/lemire/externalsortinginjava).

From the above link, just use the merge operation in your case:

```
 public static int mergeSortedFiles(List<File> files, File outputfile,
                final Comparator<String> cmp, Charset cs, boolean distinct,
                boolean append, boolean usegzip) throws IOException {
                ArrayList<BinaryFileBuffer> bfbs = new ArrayList<BinaryFileBuffer>();
                for (File f : files) {
                        final int BUFFERSIZE = 2048;
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
                        BufferedReader br;
                        if (usegzip) {
                                br = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                                new GZIPInputStream(in,
                                                        BUFFERSIZE), cs));
                        } else {
                                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        in, cs));
                        }

                        BinaryFileBuffer bfb = new BinaryFileBuffer(br);
                        bfbs.add(bfb);
                }
                BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(outputfile, append), cs));
                int rowcounter = mergeSortedFiles(fbw, cmp, distinct, bfbs);
                for (File f : files)
                        f.delete();
                return rowcounter;
        }
```

Comment: Hello Amit. Thanks for the respone but i used this source code to sort two files seperatly. My question is if there is a library to merge those two files into one

Comment: Just use the merge operation of external sorting present in that link then.

Comment: ! Yes i could do that, haven't thaught about it.. thanks! i will send feedback later